# What does test -s do?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have been handed of a code which has below condition

```
if test -s "$SOME_DIR/$some_file"
then
   ##some code
fi
```

**Question :** what is this `test -s` supposed to do? what the purpose of it?

Comment: Have you tried [`man test`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : this might sound weird but we do not have access to the console...we just do code change and migrate in the needed instance! :)

Comment: Well there are quite a few places on the Internet where can find manual pages. I  personally like the one I linked to, but there are [others](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test), and even the [official POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : its not that everyday i face this issue...but good to know where to search in next time...thanks a lot mate! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor For the future, [here](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=test+-s+%22%24SOME_DIR%2F%24some_file%22)'s a nice tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `test -s` command returns true if the file exists and is not empty ( has size bigger than 0).